# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 [ Jenkins ]

Tags: ios, macos, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to use Jenkins to build iOS apps in a slave machine. Currently I use my machine instead.

There comes up a strange error for me.

In **brief** 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

In **detail** 
http://pastebin.com/dWKwWwE6

I am using Xcode 5 on Maverick. What I just need is a hint or tutorials how to make a build systematically which can give me a clear understanding on the whole building process.

I am a web architect and believe me I have no native engineering experiences yet.

Thanks Folks
Tin Aung Lin

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the log it seems building "Test AppTest.app" failed because "Test App.app" was not yet built. Also, codesigning seems to have failed. I don't think these problems are Jenkins-related. Does it build when you invoke the build yourself running Xcode on your laptop?